# predict (glmFit) is return the same probabilities for test and training data

Tags: r, glm, logistic-regression

I have a data set and its structure is given below :

```
Id Fail Leverage CumulProfit Liquid OverDueDebt WorkCap OperProfit ShortDebt GuarDebt StateLag     FiscalLag InFinan Links CapStruct
1 0 1 0.12911 0.05359 0 0.0765 0.09662 0 0 128 105 0.07439 0 0.81122

dim(dataSet) 

[1] 885  15
```

I am trying to fit Logistic Regression model and my response variable is Fail, Attribute Id is ignored while fitting the model. Remaining 13 predictors are involved in fitting the glm model.

I have divided 80% of the data as Training data and the remaining 20% is kept aside for Test

```
indexes = sample(1:nrow(creditDataFrame), size = 0.8 * (nrow(creditDataFrame)),replace = FALSE)
trainingData = creditDataFrame[indexes,]
dim(trainingData)
[1] 708  15

testData = creditDataFrame[-indexes,]
dim(testData)
[1] 177  15
```

This is how its fitted to the glm model

```
glmFit = glm(Fail~.-Id, data = trainingData[,c(2:15)], family = binomial)
predict(glmFit, testData[,c(3:15)],type = "response")
```

Now when I am trying to predict the response for the test data(where I am not including column1 which is Id and column2 which is Fail because its the response variable that I am trying to predict), it gives me almost all the probabilities. From what I have understood , I should have got only 177 probabilities which is equal to the number of rows in my test data set.

The strange thing is it gives me the same result while predicting the trainingData as well as the testData predicted in the above line of code.

```
predict(glmFit,type = "response")
```

I am just pasting first 5 probabilities , but its giving me for all 885 probabilities even though I am just trying to predict for the small testData set.

```
      721        496        534         23        194 
    0.31854799 0.65284894 0.19175386 0.04859473 0.10326100
```

Comment: Hi, what seems strange is your call to `glm`. You exclude Id in the formula, but this was not selected in your data: `data = trainingData[,c(2:15)]`.

Comment: Even if I pass the entire training data set, it gives me the same results:  glmFit = glm(Fail~.-Id, data = trainingData, family = binomial)

Comment: Your `glm` call with `id` included in the formula but not in the dataset will have thrown an error. Besides that the above code should work. Try starting a new R session and rerunning (btw you could make the example reproducible using `mtcars` dataset)